# Call the web Browser using content Provider

Tags: android

I am a hybrid app developer and want to develop a android app. I am new android . I want to open the given link in the web browser.  I will do this as below in hybrid app in javascript

```
<a href="www.google.co.in">www.google.co.in</a>
```

I need to implement this in android . How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the cod to implement the above. In any function add the below code .

```
Intent i = new
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse(“http://www.amazon.com”));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use intents

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.co.in"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Intents: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

This link by @giacomoni is great too (from android tutorials): http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

I'm at phone now so I cant put links

Comment: This link can also be useful: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code that's responsible for the button's (or any other element's) click event:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("www.google.co.in"));      
startActivity(intent);
```